# cannot get req.body property from http post method

Tags: javascript, express, curl, request

I have a http post request which I'm not able to get the params from. This is posted to an express application. I can inspect the request body not req.body.sign.
For testing I'm using a curl command but even w/ simplified version, I'm unable to access payResult. Is there an issue w/ curl options ? Is the object formatted poorly,  any help would be appreciated.

```
curl --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --request POST --data '{ sign: '68FF103130163F52A2B8178F73BFAB2CE322A4F5EB48DECD11FFE75AF2E2F3803CD07DBAB1F311700077EEC184463173F6773F059BD5783E61B7F04CBB80C9E333DABA2066774F2BEDB53EA6243B6FA40ADC2700A4C75EEDE700ABF493B60D9D62175C50774782ED6F10323A389DB04E29009572323EC1FAFCEB34D204CECD90', body: '{"payResult":"SUCCESS"}' }' https://somedomain.com/notifyUrl/
```

Comment: a log of the request body produces something like this:

`code` { sign: '68FF103130163F52A2B8178F73BFAB2CE322A4F5EB48DECD11FFE75AF2E2F3803CD07DBAB1F311700077EEC184463173F6773F059BD5783E61B7F04CBB80C9E333DABA2066774F2BEDB53EA6243B6FA40ADC2700A4C75EEDE700ABF493B60D9D62175C50774782ED6F10323A389DB04E29009572323EC1FAFCEB34D204CECD90', body: '{"txnId":808280507302639782,"payResult":"SUCCESS"}' }

Answer (score 1):

Replace Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded with Content-Type: application/json,Because you post json data.

Comment: thanks. I think I'm misinterpreting the log output. the request (from a 3rd party API) is www-form-urlencoded and includes stringified JSON formatted data. It's difficult to reproduce in curl.